# How to show html code for images in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

is there a way to show html code (for images only) in WYSIWYG mode of tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but not out of the box.
You will have to [write an onw plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) for this containing code like this

```
$(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).find('img').each(function(){
    var html = this.outerHTML;
});
```